# How do I make notications appear on Chrome and Chrome OS, like Pushbullet and Google Now?

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromium

Pushbullet and Google Now have notifications, which can pop up depending on time or place or any other trigger. If I have to add this feature to my app, how can I do it?

Comment: [`notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications as pointed out by @Moin in the comments. This will only work for people that decide to install your chrome app on desktop (no support for chrome in Android)
- Using the new push notifications APIs as described in
  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/

The latter is probably recommended if you can live with the following caveats:

- It's a bit more basic API
- Users needs to opt in via a prompt
- The site needs to be https